# What is the meaning of the square box around question answer?

Tags: discussion

I read the whole FAQ and I did not find that answer.

Comment: I think you need to post a screenshot of what you're seeing, as I'm not sure which box you're talking about

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about the dotted line? Red means there are no answers. Light green means the question has been answered, and dark green means an answer has been accepted.

Comment: Yeah it is the dotted box, but sometimes it be full red or full green what do it mean?

Comment: I told you already.